# Is displaying tags and categories on recent posts unnecessary?

Tags: usability, website-design, tags, ordering

I am creating an online community platform where users can post blog-like items. I currently have made a design that displays recent posts, along with a sidebar where users can filter existing posts using categories and tags. Clicking on a posts' title will bring the user to the full article.

[image]

-

The idea is that when a user checks, for example, the `tutorial` category along with the `Magento 2` tag, only posts with *at least* these types are displayed and all other items will be hidden, like this picture:

[image]

As you can see these categories and tags are also featured in the recent posts. Users can also click on these tags to filter the items on the platform accordingly.

In this case, would it usability-wise be a good idea to also include these tags on recent posts, or does it seem unnecessary and/or confusing should I stick with displaying categories and tags on the sidebar only?

Edit: As DasBeasto asked in the comments, the filtered posts are those that have **at least** the selected tags.

Comment: Does it filter to posts that have *only* those two tags, or *at least* those two tags? Lets say that post in your last image also had the tag **Wordpress**. If you hid those tags the user wouldn't know that it may be a Wordpress only solution.

Comment: It filters to posts that have _at least_ those tags. I edited in the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do you have plans for anything other than desktop?

Since designers have little control over viewport size, that filter bar may be need to be either minimized, or become adaptive to perhaps a horizontal filter bar. In either case, the filter takes up less (or no) space.

Even in a full screen view it's hard to keep track of the filtered state.

By keeping categories and tags visible in the scrolling article/tutorial teasers, users can still useful information. You can do this with some subtle design. Coloring the categories might be overload in this case because you have to interpret the colors as well.

As an example, here's how [mashable](http://mashable.com) puts a category in gray text above the article title:

[image]

**Categories vs Tags**

Right now, it appears you're treating Categories and tags as the same visually.

Categories are usually discreet and singular. In most editorial sites they represent a news section. An article can be in only one category, but it can have multiple tags associated with it. There are some sites that seem to mix the two without consequence, but they're often graphically depicted differently.

I see that you have a list view, but I assume there's a detail page for each of these items.
Since you seem to have a site geared towards reading and learning (content), you'll often see on article detail pages a pattern of the category placed in a subtle way close to the article title. This saves the user time if he / she knows they're in the right place.

Tags are often clustered at the end of the article, where the reader can click and drill into related concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The platform will focus mostly on desktop users. Mobile devices have a lower priority and will be dealt with at a later stage. I agree that categories are different than tags, and initially had the idea of only displaying the category type like you showed in your image, and leave the tags at the bottom of the article. So, what I understand is that it would be better to only display a category type when scrolling trough the teasers and delete the allocated tags?

Comment: You might try doing both, but maybe make the tags in the list page very subtle, underneath the summary text like you have already. It's one of those situations where some subtle visual design can make a big difference.

Comment: Thanks, just need to point out that this is a wireframe and not a visual design, so it might look ugly, but it is design to test the usability.

Comment: Oh of course! I love balsamiq for exactly this fact. Otherwise teams get sucked into [bikeshedding](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Parkinsons-law-of-triviality-bikeshedding) discussions. :)